# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' 430

Tags: c#

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
Error   2   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

This is for the  iD only, Password is a string

How do I make this, the iD an int.Parse?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    iD = dr["@ID"].ToString();
                    password = dr["@PASSWORD"].ToString();
                }

                if (iD == id && password == pw)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogNotification = "ID/Password is incorrect";
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Like this int.Parse(iD);

Comment: if you are a programmer change it to  `if (iD == id.ToString() && password == pw)` but if you are a developer use one of the answers below ;)

Answer (score 2):

int.Parse will throw an Exception so I advice you to use [int.TryParse]
Example:

```
        string numberAsString = "10";
        int onlyNumber;
        if (!int.TryParse(numberAsString, out onlyNumber))
        {
            // failed to convert string to int, do something
        }
```

in your example:

```
        int iD;
        if (!int.TryParse(dr["@ID"].ToString(), out iD))
        {
            // failed to convert string to int, do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line no 3 with this

```
 iD = Convert.ToInt32(dr["@ID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace:

```
iD = int.Parse(dr["@ID"].ToString());
```

given `iD` is a `var` type such that the compiler can automatically alter the type. If not, you need to do this on the `if` level:

```
if (int.Parse(iD) == id && password == pw)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `@ID` is an integer in your data row, I would suggest to *not do any conversion at all*, not to string and not back to integer. Simply *retrieve it as an integer* using [the Field extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
iD = dr.Field<int>("@ID");
```